# Assembly instruction to dereference a char pointer and return the result

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, att

An exercise in my CS book asks for a short (x86-64) assembly snippet for a function that takes a char pointer as argument and returns the (first) character pointed by it.

The solution proposed in the book is as follows :

```
movq (%rdi), %rax
movb (%rax), %al
```

I would have thought that one instruction would be sufficient :

```
movb (%rdi), %al
```

Are the two equivalent ? What am I missing ?

Comment: The first does two dereferences, as if you had a double pointer.

Comment: Which book is this, so future readers confused by the same error in the same book can find this more easily?

Comment: @PeterCordes I realized after reading El Profesor's answer  that the book is correct, that a double dereferencing was needed indeed. When I wrote this question I left as many details as possible to keep it simple and readable

Comment: Oh, so it's not a `char*` arg.   :/  Or it takes it by reference and you forgot to mention that.  Not sure how to fix this misleading question.  Maybe include the actual wording from the book and then the answer can correct your interpretation of it as `char*`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I changed the title and added a small modification to the wording of the question, I think this should suffice as a fix

Comment: IMO that's significantly worse; your new title is way less specific.  People searching and looking through question titles won't have any idea what sequences of instructions the question is about.  And in the question body "among other things" doesn't modify the fact that the arg is claimed to be a char pointer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Feel free to delete this question if you think it best, or modify it anyway you please. As you probably already noticed, my beginner misunderstanding made me state some sort of X/Y question (I got exactly the explanation I needed however). Apologies if this can't be made useful for other people

Comment: I guess we might as well leave it.  Since it turns out it wasn't an error in a book,  the source is less important and we might as well just leave it.  With this specific title and a useful answer, maybe it will be of some use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first snippet, two pointer dereferences  occur:

```
movq (%rdi), %rax
movb (%rax), %al
```

That is, the 8-byte memory location pointed by `rdi` is loaded into `rax`. Then, the 1-byte memory location pointed by `rax` is loaded into `al`. You can think of it as fully dereferencing a *pointer to a pointer to `char`* (i.e., `char **`).

Whereas in your second snippet, `movb (%rdi), %al`, there is a single pointer dereference, i.e., the 1-byte location pointed by `rdi` is loaded into `al`. You can think of it as dereferencing a *pointer to `char`* (i.e., `char *`).

Comment: The preferred way to load a byte in x86-64 is `movzbl (%rax), %eax`, writing a fresh value to RAX, not merging a new low byte into the old RAX.  (Especially if you're loading into a different destination register that wasn't already an input dependency for this instruction.)